# Is it possible to use cdk-drag-and-drop directives across multiple child components?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm working on a project which uses Angular's cdk-drag-and-drop functionality to be able to sort a grid of cards. Because it's a grid, I'm using [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyz1eb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) as an example. The example does exactly what I want to achieve.

There is a slight difference however with my app. In my situation, the grid itself and all the items on the grid (cards) are separate Angular components. This means I have the following two HTML's..

The grid HTML:

```html
<div class="example-container" cdkDropListGroup>
  <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="dropListEnterPredicate" (cdkDropListDropped)="dropListDropped($event)"></div>
  <div cdkDropList *ngFor="let card of cards" [cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="dropListEnterPredicate" (cdkDropListDropped)="dropListDropped($event)">
    <my-card-component [card]="card" etc..></my-custom-component>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the HTML for each individual card in the grid ('my-card-component'):

```html
<div class="card" cdkDrag (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event)">
  <!-- A lot more html -->
  <div cdkDragHandle>Drag me</div>
</div>
```

However, this doesn't give the desired effect. Then, when I move the HTML for the card back into it's parent component HTML file (so, the grid) it actually **does work**. So apparently, using the cdk directives across multiple components doesn't work. Is this expected behaviour? Or should it work across multiple components?

I've tried adding the `cdkDrag`-directive onto the `my-card-component` html-element, because that would keep that directive in the grid component. This makes the card draggable, but I can't drop it anywhere. Also, it makes the entire card draggable and thus seems to ignore the `cdkDragHandle` in the child component. So this didn't bring me any further.

Preferably, I would keep the separation of components and still use the cdk's directives. Is this possible?